# How to find the distribution of a single variable based on population distribution

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, distribution

I am trying to find the age distribution of the subset of married people of a population. However, I realise that just visualising the married count by age (Figure 1) is highly dependent on the original distribution of ages in the population, as shown in Figure 2.

How can I determine the distribution of a boolean feature like isMarried = True based on the original distribution?

[image: age distribution of married people]

[image: age distribution of population]

Comment: Wecome to DataScienceSE. Is this homework?

Comment: Hi, this is just further personal exploration of a data set that was initially set as a homework task.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the conditional probability "married given age".

For any age value $a$, you can calculate:

$$p(Married=true|Age=a)=\frac{p(Married=true \wedge Age=a)}{p(Age=a)}$$

For the calculation you can directly use the frequency instead of the probability:

- the top part is the number of *married* people aged $a$
- the bottom part is the total number of people aged $a$